# How to make a JS code that can change iframe content when reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, iframe

I want to make a changable iframe images. I tried lot but cannot find a way to fix my code. Please help me fix my code or if there any other method please let me know.

HTML

```
<iframe class="img-responsive center-block element-spacing-md" id="banner" width="970" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 970px; height: 250px;" ></iframe><iframe class="img-responsive center-block element-spacing-md" id="banner" width="970" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 970px; height: 250px;" ></iframe>
```

JS

```
var image = new Array ();
    image[0] = '"//s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/4408939339/1629903098931/index.html"';
    image[1] = '"//s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/4823240283/1652207585517/index.html"';
    image[2] = '"//s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/4823240283/1652207585517/index.html"';
    var size = image.length
    var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
    
var output='src='+image[x];
console.log(output);

document.getElementById("banner").innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: Why are you setting the innerHTML of the iframe element? That makes little sense. The innerHTML of an iframe element, is the content _between_ the opening and closing tag - which would only get shown, if the browser did not know how to handle iframes in the first place. And even if that was not the case - just writing `src="..."` as HTML code, has never shown an image.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [set iframe content](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+set+iframe+content)

Comment: @freedomn-m nope dude!

Comment: @CBroe then how can i do it

Comment: How would you make the iframe display one of those images, statically, without any scripting & "randomness" involved ...?

Comment: `document.getElementById("banner").src = image[x];`?

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks buddy I'm able to manage that..and also your comment is the answer.Thank You anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It wasn't clear (to me) exactly what you were trying to do hence only a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need to make a iframe that changes when reloading try this..
Thanks!

html

```
<iframe class="img-responsive center-block element-spacing-md" id="banner" width="970" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 970px; height: 250px;" src=></iframe>
```

js

```
var image = new Array ();
    image[0] = "//s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/4408939339/1629903098931/index.html";
    image[1] = "//s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/4823240283/1652207585517/index.html";
    image[2] = "//s0.2mdn.net/dfp/370694/4823240283/1652207585517/index.html";
    var size = image.length
    var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())
    
var output=image[x];
console.log(output)

document.getElementById("banner").src=output;
```